# how to dump my mysql database with data and migrate the dump data to postgresql database+rails

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

i have spending time i did't solve and all most search give me blow code:

"mysqldump -u root -p  -h localhost youspin_development5 > youspin_dump.sql"

and I have tried but show me something like that:

```
mysql> mysqldump -u root -p  -h localhost youspin_development5 > youspin_dump.sql
    -> 
    -> 
    -> 
    -> 
    ->
```